# DBT: Convert string into list of dictionary which is passed as --vars

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I am newbie to DBT and Jinja. I am trying to below variables as String and want to convert it to dictionary/json and iterate over it as a list

command to run:

```
dbt --debug run --models run_model --vars '{"filter_cols" : "{'A': 'val1','cond': 'AND'}"}'
```

Its gets passed as below to DBT:

```yaml
['{"A":"val1","cond":"AND"}']
```

I expect it to be passed as below to DBT:

```yaml
[{"A":"val1","cond":"AND"}]
```

Any sort of help and advice is much appreciated in advance.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you're running:

```
dbt --debug run --models run_model --vars '{"filter_cols" : "{'A': 'val1','cond': 'AND'}"}'
```

You wrap the inner dictionary in quotes, so it's getting passed in as a string. The `--vars` tag [expects a YAML dictionary](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/using-variables/#defining-variables-on-the-command-line). Remove the quotes around your inner dictionary and it should work:

```
dbt --debug run --models run_model --vars '{"filter_cols" : {'A': 'val1','cond': 'AND'}}'
```