# How can dbt build with a json var through the command console

Tags: python, jinja2, dbt

I would like to define a json var for a run of **dbt** through the command console.

This *json* is generated in python with a database schema, something like `[{'name': 'Name', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}...]`

I tried in different ways but I couldn't get it:

```
 $ dbt build --vars 'json: [{'name': 'Name', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}...]'
```

In this case I got the error "while parsing a block mapping" probably because of the single quotes from JSON.

I tried to convert the single quotes to double quotes in python with json.dumps() function and execute again something like this:

```
$ dbt build --vars 'json: [{"name": "Name", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"}...]'
```

In this case I'm getting an error like:
The `--vars` argument must be a **YAML** *dictionary*, but was of type `'str'`

I tried some more ways but with similar results.

I have to do this because I have an Airflow operator that generates this json in python with the database schema to validate and sends it via xcom to a Kubernetes Pod Operator that is in charge of launching the dbt build command with this var.

https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/using-variables

Comment: Seems like a similar problem to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71375808/dbt-convert-string-into-list-of-dictionary-which-is-passed-as-vars

Comment: @AleixCC I already read it, but sadly not the same. The inner dicts aren't wrapped in quotes :/

Comment: What if you parse the array of dicts, and pass it as a wrapped JSON? So that the format matches the one that dbt needs (a YAML dict)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a set of curlies. You want to pass in a dictionary literal that has a single set of quotes around it (so it gets read as a single string by your shell).

You have:

```bash
--vars 'json: ...'
```

You need:

```bash
--vars '{json: ...}'
```

With all the args:

```bash
$ dbt build --vars '{json: [{"name": "Name", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"}...]}'
```

Note that YAML is flexible about quoting, so this is the same as either of these:

```bash
$ dbt build --vars '{json: [{name: Name, type: STRING, mode: NULLABLE}...]}'
$ dbt build --vars '{"json": [{"name": "Name", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"}...]}'
```

Comment: thanks, I've just tried to modify the python code on airflow to change it and got the same problem when the kubernetesPodOperator executed the dbt command:
The command executed is something like this:
 $ dbt build --target=dev --vars '{json: [{"mode": "NULLABLE", "name": "Name", "type": "STRING"},.... ]}'
It says: Compilation Error:
The --vars argument must be a YAML dictionary, but was of type 'str'

Comment: I can't reproduce that. If I run the jaffle shop project with `dbt build --vars '{json: [{"name": "Name", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"}]}' `, it works. You're not actually including an ellipsis (`...`), in your code, are you? Or is it possible there is an issue with quoting in the section of code that you have omitted?

Comment: Yes @tconbeer, I wasn't including the ellipsis. We're starting to think is a problem of kubernetes pod operator and the docker image we're investigating this. If I try to execute the same command (```dbt build --vars '{json: [{"name": "Name", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"}]}'``` ) directly from my desktop command console, it launches dbt and creates the table. I will be keeping update, thanks!